# Mapreduce job submission vs Spark job submission

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am going through various documents to understand how spark job submission varies from mapreduce job submission , is there a diagram that illustrates like mapreduce job submission mentioned in hadoop definitive guide ?

And also, the spark application will also be submitted from edge node like it does in mapreduce ( there is no strict rule but i guess that is practice that is followed )

Comment: Not sure why this question is down voted? Instead, you would have given the reason why this is down voted instead of down voting in the first place ?

Answer (score 1):

### MapReduce Submission:

You can submit MapReduce v1 jobs and YARN applications (MapReduce v2 and other applications that run on YARN) to the same cluster. A job or an application can be submitted to the cluster in the following ways:

- The hadoop jar command submits a MapReduce v1 job or MapReduce v2
  application.
- The yarn jar command submits an application.
- An external application submits a MapReduce v1 job or an application.
- An ecosystem component generates and submits an application or a
  MapReduce v1 job.
- The hadoop job command submits a MapReduce v1 job or MapReduce v2
  application.
- The mapred job command submits a MapReduce v2 application.

Example MapReduce Submission:

```
./yarn jar $YARN_EXAMPLES/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar
```

### Submitting Spark Applications

Once a user application is bundled, it can be launched using the bin/spark-submit script. This script takes care of setting up the classpath with Spark and its dependencies, and can support different cluster managers and deploy modes that Spark supports

- Run application locally on 8 cores

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master local[8] \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  100
```

- Run on a Spark standalone cluster in client deploy mode

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master spark://207.184.161.138:7077 \
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --total-executor-cores 100 \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  1000
```

- Run on a Spark standalone cluster in cluster deploy mode with
  supervise

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master spark://207.184.161.138:7077 \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --supervise \
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --total-executor-cores 100 \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  1000
```

- Run on a YARN cluster

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=XXX
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode cluster \  # can be client for client mode
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --num-executors 50 \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  1000
```

- Run a Python application on a Spark standalone cluster

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --master spark://207.184.161.138:7077 \
  examples/src/main/python/pi.py \
  1000
```

- Run on a Mesos cluster in cluster deploy mode with supervise

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master mesos://207.184.161.138:7077 \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --supervise \
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --total-executor-cores 100 \
  http://path/to/examples.jar \
  1000
```

Comment: thanks a lot for detailed explanation. How spark submission is different from map reduce submission, I am looking for a diagram of spark submission ( similar to https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/hadoop-the-definitive/9781491901687/ch07.html )